# Collect Mousewheeler trigger and then call function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I build a simple zoom effect with javascript/jquery but struggle to make this one a bit smoother.

```
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseWheelHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseWheelHandler, false);
var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
```

When `delta > 0` I increase the width of my container, when `delta < 0` I decrease the width of my container. 
See Code snippet for basic example:

```js
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseWheelHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseWheelHandler, false);
function mouseWheelHandler(e) {
  var current_width = $('div').width();
  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
  if(delta == -1) {
      $('div').css('width', current_width / 1.1);
  } else {
      $('div').css('width', current_width * 1.1);
  }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-image:url(https://placehold.it/500x500);height:500px;width:500px;">
```

I know want that to collect the scrolls a user performances and only scroll once. 
I tried using `setTimeout()`and set it to 1000ms, collect all `delta` values into one variable and then zoom in that often:

```js
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseWheelHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseWheelHandler, false);
var zoom_factor = 0;
function mouseWheelHandler(e) {
  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
  setTimeout(function(){
    zoom_factor = zoom_factor + delta
    console.log(zoom_factor);
  }, 1000);
  zoom(zoom_factor);
}
     

function zoom(zoom_factor) {
  var current_width = $('div').width();
  var new_width = current_width;
  if(zoom_factor > 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < zoom_factor; i++) {
      new_width = new_width * 1.1
    }
  } else if (zoom_factor < 0) {
    zoom_factor = zoom_factor * -1
    for(var i = 0; i < zoom_factor; i++) {
      new_width = new_width / 1.1
    }
  }
  $('div').css('width',new_width);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://placehold.it/500x500);height:500px;width:500px;">
```

This doesn't work because even when the timeout is still passing, the zoom effects are all triggered.

Is there a way to call the `zoom()` after the `setTimeout()` is finished and is only called once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var zoom_factor = 0;
var timeout;
function mouseWheelHandler(e) {
  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
  // reset timeout
  clearTimeout(timeout);

  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    // call zoom() once
    zoom(zoom_factor);

    // reset zoomfactor
    zoom_factor = 0;
  }, 1000);

  // Calculate zoom factor
  zoom_factor = zoom_factor + delta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

param in `settimeout()`:

```
function mouseWheelHandler(e) {
  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
  setTimeout(function(){
    zoom_factor = zoom_factor + delta
    console.log(zoom_factor);
  }, 1000, zoom(zoom_factor));
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseWheelHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseWheelHandler, false);
var zoom_factor = 0;
function mouseWheelHandler(e) {
  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
  setTimeout(function(){
    zoom_factor = zoom_factor + delta
    console.log(zoom_factor);
  }, 10, zoom(zoom_factor));
}
     

function zoom(zoom_factor) {
  var current_width = $('div').width();
  var new_width = current_width;
  if(zoom_factor > 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < zoom_factor; i++) {
      new_width = new_width * 1.1
    }
  } else if (zoom_factor < 0) {
    zoom_factor = zoom_factor * -1
    for(var i = 0; i < zoom_factor; i++) {
      new_width = new_width / 1.1
    }
  }
  $('div').css('width',new_width);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://placehold.it/500x500);height:500px;width:500px;">
```